# Ripple effect not working with shared element transition and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I have a shared element transition when a `RecyclerView item click starts a detail Activity, but the ripple effect on the item click is never visible

**Start Activity with shared element transition**

```
Intent intent = IntentUtils.createDetailsIntent(InspectionListFragment.this.getContext(), record);
Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
                  view, getString(R.string.transition_element)).toBundle();
getActivity().startActivity(intent, options);
```

I noticed this log message

```
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x95e86600 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xaa6c2760
```

If I remove the transition, the ripple works (and I don't see this message).

**Delay Activity start using Handler**

If I use a Handler with `postDelayed` to start the Activity, the results were mixed. I see the ripple, but the transition is not as smooth:

```
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = IntentUtils.createDetailsIntent(InspectionListFragment.this.getContext(), record);
            Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
                  view, getString(R.string.transition_element)).toBundle();
            getActivity().startActivity(intent, options);
        }
    }, 200);
```

**Using ListView**

Note that using a `ListView` with the same item layout and `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` works fine. Unfortunately this is not suitable.

**The item layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: Having exactly the same problem

Comment: I have not found a better solution. I'm interested in understanding why there is such a difference between `ListView` and `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when I had an `ImageView` within the card as the shared element. I was able to resolve it by using the `CardView` as the source view for the shared element transition (and the ripple effect) instead.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/itemCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="@{onItemClick}"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >
```

I'm using data binding, but the shared element change was essentially just selecting a different source view:

```
// before:
//onItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), getItemId(), Pair.create((View)b.itemImage, "activity_image"));

// after:
onItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), getItemId(), Pair.create((View)b.itemCard, "activity_image"));
```

Before this, I also tried using `postDelayed` with a short delay, but I found that approach added too much delay to the navigation for my liking.